# How to properly forwarding EditText components with soft keyboard with inner layouts without overlapping?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing a small form within a ExpandableListActivity on my application, which is composed with plenty EditText components, and most of them are numeric fields.

In order to improve usability on filling I put the attribute `android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"` in each of those EditTexts, so that whenever the user hits Enter on the soft keyboard the focus is forwarded to the next input field.

This works, the focus goes next, but when the next EditText to be focused is inside another LinearLayout, the keyboard doesn't pan down and its inner focused fields stay overlapped by the keyboard.

Any inputs on how can I make it work for this inner edit boxes?

Here's the layout:

```
<EditText
     android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer" />

<TextView
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FC (bat/min):"
    android:textColor="@color/monthview_grid_color" />

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer" />

<TextView
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FR (inc/min):"
    android:textColor="@color/monthview_grid_color" />

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer" />

<TextView
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PA:"
    android:textColor="@color/monthview_grid_color" />

<LinearLayout
     android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:numeric="integer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X" />

    <EditText
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:numeric="integer" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sat. (%):"
    android:textColor="@color/monthview_grid_color" />

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer" />
```

And here's the snipped from my AndroidManifest.xml regarding the related activity:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.FormActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the android:nextFocusDown of the edit text above the linearlayout. You only need actionNext, and actionDone on the last element.

Also, numeric is deprecated, use inputType="number" instead.

Comment: You mean it's only needed to put actionNext and actionDone on the one last edittext element? If so, I tried here and it didn't worked on changing focus to the next. Actually, also the problem is not that the focus isn't moving but, the soft keyboard isn't properly panning down, overlapping the form.